# Angular 2: strategies for doing multi-language apps/component

Tags: angular

I am struggling with how to develop and structure multi-language app/components in Angular 2.

In Angular 1.x I did something like this in the route config:

```js
appDesktop.config([
  "$stateProvider", "$urlRouterProvider", "$locationProvider", function($stateProvider: IAppStateProvider, $urlRouterProvider: angular.ui.IUrlRouterProvider, $locationProvider: ng.ILocationProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");
    $stateProvider.state("home_en", {
      url: "/",
      views: {
        'header': {
          templateUrl: "/AngularJs/Controllers/main/d.mainHeader_en.html",
          controller: "mainController",
          controllerAs: "main"
        },
        'content': {
          templateUrl: "/AngularJs/Controllers/main/d.mainContent_en.html"
        }
      },
      language: LanguageChoiceEnum.English,
      changeLangState: "home_es",
      title: "Welcome"
    });
    $stateProvider.state("home_es", {
      url: "/",
      views: {
        'header': {
          templateUrl: "/AngularJs/Corollers/main/d.mainHeader_es.html",
          controller: "mainController",
          controllerAs: "main"
        },
        'content': {
          templateUrl: "/AngularJs/Controllers/main/d.mainContent_es.html"
        }
      },
      language: LanguageChoiceEnum.Spanish,
      changeLangState: "home_en",
      title: "Bienvenido"
    });
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  }
]);
```

So, in this snippet, if someone was on the "Home" page (english version) and they chose to go to the spanish version, I would redirect to the "home_es" state.  Worked well.

With Angular 2, I am gathering that you can't dynamically assign views to components (or can you?).  Hence I am trying to figure out how to accomplish something similar and still keep my code DRY.  Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's the advantage to using separate templates for language changes vs. using properties on the components to inject the correct language's text?

Comment: @SnareChops Well I am not sure whats best.  One strategy I have considered is to inject correct language text.  May be this is best solution.

Comment: This is probably the path of least resistance, and also I think the most maintainable. If you support 20 languages, and have 20 nearly identical template files, and then you need to change a class, add a button, or make some modification to the template, then you will need to update 20 files. Having a common template, but injected language will make this easier allowing for only the text itself to be the difference. Images, CSS classes, HTML attributes can also be handled this way, so if one language needs a different image from another, then the image's url can be injected in the same fashion

Comment: Yes, what you are saying seems very sound.  Excellent idea about dynamically changing images too.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing the whole template you can make use of angularJS custom filter to translate the text you need to translate to required language by passing the language flag as a parameter.

I have implemented in many applications this approach and it works like charm
check [this](http://%20%20%20%20//%20Best%20way%20to%20change%20language%20Globally%20is%20to%20use%20pipes%20and%20send%20the%20language%20parameter%20as%20an%20argument.%20%20%20%20%20//%20This%20would%20automatically%20change%20the%20Language%20across%20the%20components%20where%20the%20language%20pipe%20is%20utilized.%20%20%20%20%20//%20The%20following%20example%20can%20be%20used%20to%20supple%20multiple%20language%20at%20a%20time%20and%20can%20be%20used%20to%20change%20Language%20dynamically%20on%20a%20single%20click%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20//%20for%20example:%20**language.pipe.ts**%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%60import%20%7B%20Pipe,%20PipeTransform,%20OnInit,%20OnChanges%20%7D%20from%20'@angular/core';%20%20%20%20%20import%20%7B%20LanguageService%20%7D%20from%20'../services/language.service';%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20@Pipe(%7B%20%20%20%20%20%09name:%20'language'%20%20%20%20%20%7D)%20%20%20%20%20export%20class%20LanguagePipe%20implements%20PipeTransform%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%09constructor(%20%20%20%20%20%09%09public%20lang:%20LanguageService%20%20%20%20%20%09)%20%7B%20%7D%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%09transform(value:%20string,%20args?:%20any):%20any%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%09%09return%20this.lang.getLang(value);%20%20%20%20%20%09%7D%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20%20%20%60%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20//%20**language.service.ts**%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%60import%20%7B%20Injectable%20%7D%20from%20'@angular/core';%20%20%20%20%20import%20%7B%20HttpClient,%20HttpHeaders%20%7D%20from%20'@angular/common/http';%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20@Injectable()%20%20%20%20%20export%20class%20LanguageService%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%09selectedLanguage%20=%20'ch';%20%20%20%20%20%09segmentsNames:%20any%20=%20%7B%7D;%20%20%20%20%20%09constantSegmentNames:%20any%20=%20%7B%7D;%20%20%20%20%20%09language%20=%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%09%09undefined:%20%7B%20'en':%20'',%20'ch':%20''%20%7D,%20%20%20%20%20%09%09null:%20%7B%20'en':%20'',%20'ch':%20''%20%7D,%20%20%20%20%20%09%09'':%20%7B%20'en':%20'',%20'ch':%20''%20%7D,%20%20%20%20%20%09%09'hello':%20%7B%20'en':%20'Hello',%20'ch':%20'%E4%BD%A0%E5%A5%BD'%20%7D,%20%20%20%20%20%09%09'world':%20%7B%20'en':%20'World',%20'ch':%20'%E4%B8%96%E7%95%8C'%20%7D%20%20%20%20%20%09%7D;%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%09constructor(private%20_http:%20HttpClient)%20%7B%20%7D%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%09getLang(value:%20string,%20args?:%20any):%20any%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%09%09if%20(this.language[value])%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%09%09%09return%20this.language[value][this.selectedLanguage];%20%20%20%20%20%09%09%7D%20%20%20%20%20%09%09return%20value;%20%20%20%20%20%09%7D%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%09/**%20%20%20%20%20%09%20*%20@function%20that%20is%20used%20to%20toggle%20the%20selected%20language%20among%20'en'%20and%20'ch'%20%20%20%20%20%09%20*/%20%20%20%20%20%09changeLanguage()%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%09%09if%20(this.selectedLanguage%20===%20'en')%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%09%09%09this.selectedLanguage%20=%20'ch';%20%20%20%20%20%09%09%7D%20else%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%09%09%09this.selectedLanguage%20=%20'en';%20%20%20%20%20%09%09%7D%20%20%20%20%20%09%7D%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20%20%20%60%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20//%20**Use%20Language%20Pipe%20in%20HTML%20AS**%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%60%3Cstrong%3E%7B%7B'hello'%20%7C%20language:lang.selectedLanguage%7D%7D%7B%7B'world'%20%7C%20language:lang.selectedLanguage%7D%7D%3C/strong%3E%60%20%20%20**PS:**%20Don't%20forget%20to%20import%20the%20pipe%20&%20service%20in%20all%20the%20components%20where%20you%20want%20to%20use%20this%20functionality%20%20**Conslusion:%20**%20%20you%20can%20write%20your%20own%20logic%20to%20fetch%20the%20appropriate%20Language.json%20file%20based%20on%20user%20selected%20language%20and%20use%20it%20in%20the%20service%20above%20mentioned) solution for more information but it is implemented in Angular5. you can make use of this technique in AngularJS also.